# loadView on a storyboard ViewController during unitTesting with XCTest

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, xctest

I have tried:

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];    
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self.asvc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addshopvc"];
    [self.asvc performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadView) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

but `-(void)viewDidLoad` doesn't get called in the View Controller. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `viewDidLoad` does get called. Are you calling your `setUp` method inside `viewDidLoad`? Your question is unclear.

Comment: nevermind, I found that I must call [self.asvc view] in order for the viewDidLoad to be called

Comment: If that's how you're getting your `viewDidLoad` to be called, then you're doing something wrong. `viewDidLoad` is a delegate method and it must be called automatically if you've implemented everything correctly. Calling some view to make that method be called means there's a big error somewhere.

Comment: I admit it is not clear, but setUp method is inside a XCTestCase Class, and I am trying to load programmatically another view controller.